# Bluemix API non-personal Jenkins user?

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud, devops

Since we utilize not only Bluemix but other services as well (and on-premise) we use our own Jenkins instead of the IBM DevOps services.

For the cf ic commands, how can I get/provide credentials for our Jenkins user?
Is it possible or do I have to create a "dummy" IBM account for this?

Answer (score 1):

Running the *cf ic login* command will retrieve the certificates from the remote service and store them under the *~/.ice/certs* directory.

You can use this keys with a third-party Jenkins service.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide Jenkins with user credentials. As you've said - the best way of doing this is probably to create a "dummy" account but you could equally use your own (provided it has all the right access).